# virt-resize complains: "virt-resize: error: You cannot use --expand when there is no surplus space to expand into."

Tags: kvm, virtualization, libvirt

I am resizing an installed KVM domain

```
# resize the partitions
virt-resize --expand /dev/vda2 --LV-expand /dev/vg_main/lv_root $VMFILE $VMFILE.tmp
```

and `virt-resize` throws an error:

```
virt-resize: error: You cannot use --expand when there is no surplus space to expand into.  You need to make the target disk larger by at least 224.0K.
```

What does this mean and how can I avoid it?

I am using [resizevm.sh](https://github.com/fubralimited/CentOS-KVM-Image-Tools/blob/master/scripts/resizevm.sh) script from [CentOS KVM Image Tools](https://github.com/fubralimited/CentOS-KVM-Image-Tools) and the script produces a dead disk image (domain doesn't boot up).

I am using the latest CentOS 6.5

Comment: What's the version of CentOS? 5 or 6? resizing dynamically like this is only available in 6.

Comment: See my SF Q&A titled: [How do you increase a KVM guest's disk space?](http://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space/)

Comment: @sim Forgot to add: CentOS 6.5. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using a modern enough version of KVM (CentOS 6+) you'll need to expand the image file prior to running the `virt-resize` command. Typically it's a 2 step process:

```
$ sudo truncate -s +2G $VMFILE
```

Followed by your resize command:

```
$ sudo virt-resize --expand /dev/vda2 --LV-expand /dev/vg_main/lv_root \
    $VMFILE $VMFILE.tmp
```

This will have the effect of expanding the `.img` file by 2GB. Change the argument to `truncate` to whatever size you'd like to expand the `.img` file by.

#### References

- [How do you increase a KVM guest's disk space?](https://serverfault.com/questions/324281/how-do-you-increase-a-kvm-guests-disk-space/)

Comment: 1. So, to expand a file, we should use a command which is named to the opposite of what it does, i.e. `truncate`? 2. I wonder how it worked previously, without the `truncate` command. Thanks, will try it!

Comment: @NickolaiLeschov - yes that step was very counter-intuitive to us as well. I believe the tool needed to be called either reduce or expand and they opted to call it by the shrinking function. You can also do what you want via `virt-manager` (the GUI).